# how to set discount price for multiple products in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, cart

I am using prestashop version 1.5.4.1

I am need to set clearance sale offer to my shopping site (particular date).

In particular date i need to set discount price for all products in my products by common.

EXAMPLE : I have 250 products in my catalog. I need to discount price $100 for all products from june-24 to june 30. How to set in a one click

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily set a "Catalog price rule" in your PrestaShop Back-office.

Go to "Price rules > Catalog price rule" and create a new rule.

It will allow you to select various criteria and the amount or percentage of reduction you would like to apply to all the related products.

You can also cumulate the criteria, example:

- For all products in the "T-shirts" category
- With "XXXXX" as a Manufacturer
- and with the color "Blue"

=> Apply a discount of 30%

Regards,

Comment: thanks bruna.Is is possible to   discount particular t-shirts in the t-shirt category. I have 50 t-shirts in my catalog.I have to set discount to paricular 10 t-shirts.is is posible?

Comment: Yes, you can use a "Cart rule" and select a specific product using the "Product selection" feature.